# Error in FTP over explicit TLS/SSL in Python

Tags: python, ssl, tcp, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to use below code to connect to FTP server over explicit TLS/SSL encryption. It fails at line 2 with error "ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer". Has anyone else faced this? any suggestions on how to fix this?

Note- this fails at line 2 so not even able to connect to FTP server. I have seen some posts where this similar error message shows up while uploading file but this error is different in my opinion.

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
ftps = FTP_TLS('ftp.MySite.com')
# login after securing control channel
ftps.login('testuser', 'testpass')           

ftps.prot_p()          
ftps.retrlines('LIST')
ftps.close()
```

Comment: Not clear if it is the same bug. But - error message is the same and there are no details in your questions which suggest that the situation is different than in in the already existing question.